# mmap file opened with "fopen" in C++

Tags: c++

After many frustrating experiences with limited support of HDF5 in many computers, I decided to write my own data container to store arrays in a binary file.

Basically, the format is very simple: each variable has a small header including a variable name, number of dimensions, actual size of each dimension and variable type. The data of one variable is stored right after the header. Variables are stored one after the other.

Read/write operations of header files are conveniently done using fseek, fread, fwrite and therefore I have opened the file using fopen, which returns a FILE*.

The problem is that if I want to update part of the values of one array on disk, the cleanest way to do it is using memory mapping (in my opinion). Looking at the documentation of mmap, it is possible to mmap files opened with "open", which return an int. But my file was already opened with "fopen".

Is it possible to mmap a section of a FILE*? How?

Comment: What is memmap? Do you mean mmap?

Comment: _If is possible to memmap a section of a FILE*?_ **No**. There is no need either. Once you `mmap` a file, you have it all in memory, no other IO operations are needed, so `FILE*` is totally redundant.

Comment: FILE* is not redundant if you also want to do other operations apart from updating values of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `fileno` function:

> int fileno(FILE *stream);
>
> The function fileno() examines the argument stream and returns its integer file descriptor.

You can call that on your file stream and pass the result to `mmap`. Either that or just use `open` instead of `fopen` to get a file descriptor in the first place since parsing the header via a memory map is probably easier than using `fseek` and `fread`.